# Extract columns with first few characters of the column name from multiple csv

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, group-concat

I am trying to extract specific columns from  multiple csv files and merge them into one. Each file contains 265 columns and extracting specific columns with their index number is very difficult. Is their an efficient do accomplish these task.

I have around 120 csv files.

Comment: Could you provide any more information about the csv? What columns do you want to take? Are you using ',' as separator?

Comment: Hi @Keredu, thanks for your reply. I am attaching a small snippet of the huge column sets. and the rows have for the respective columns are different. Yes they are ',' separated.

Comment: Please include your python code which you have tried already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution in pandas to extract two columns by name from all *.csv files in the current directory.

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
seek_cols = ["FccFaultB1", "FccFaultB2"]
infiles = glob("*.csv")

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=seek_cols)

for infile in infiles:
    data = pd.read_csv(infile)[seek_cols]
    df = df.append(data)
```

In my case, test1.csv:

```
FccFaultB0,FccFaultB1,FccFaultB2,FccFaultB3
0,0,0,0
```

and test2.csv:

```
FccFaultB0,FccFaultB1,FccFaultB2,FccFaultB3
1,1,1,1
```

Resulting in df:

```
  FccFaultB1 FccFaultB2
0          1          1
0          0          0
```

Comment: Thanks@Joe. This looks quite a solution. But is there any way I can extract more than two columns at once. I used iloc and tried to extract 20 columns using the column index.  at once, but it shows out of boundary error.